# How to increase memory for GAP in MAC

Tags: macos, memory-limit

How to resolve this problem? I encounter this when solving this problem

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(120);;

gap> rep:=RegularActionHomomorphism(G);;

gap> H:=Image(rep,G);

<permutation group of size 120 with 5 generators>
gap> mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(H),x->PermutationMat(x,120,GF(5)));
gap> A:=Algebra(GF(5),mats);
<algebra over GF(5), with 5 generators>
gap>  R:=RadicalOfAlgebra(A);
<algebra of dimension 96 over GF(5)>
gap> gens:=List(Basis(R),x->x+One(A));;
gap> B:=Group(gens);
<matrix group with 96 generators>
gap> LoadPackage("Recog");
true
gap> Size(RecognizeGroup(B));
F dim= 120 field=5  0      
12621774483536188886587657044524579674771302961744368076324462890625
gap> 5^96;
12621774483536188886587657044524579674771302961744368076324462890625
gap> LoadPackage("matgrp");
Matrix Group Interface routines by A. Hulpke
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
true
gap> ff:=FittingFreeLiftSetup(B);;
```

Now error is this

```
Error, reached the pre-set memory limit
(change it with the -o command line option) in
  return SiftedVectorForGaussianRowSpace( 
   LeftActingDomain( UnderlyingLeftModule( B ) ), BasisVectors( B ), 
   B!.heads, v )
 ; at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/lib/vspcrow.gi:435 called from 
SiftedVector( basis, vec * g 
 ) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/pkg/matgrp/lib/recograt.gi:39 called from
op( orb[i], gens[j] 
 ) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/pkg/orb/gap/orbits.gi:1206 called from
AddGeneratorsToOrbit( SS!.orb, [ r.rem ] 
 ); at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/pkg/genss/gap/genss.gi:1222 called from
AddGeneratorToStabilizerChain( topS, x 
 ); at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/pkg/genss/gap/genss.gi:807 called from
GENSS_RandomElementFromAbove( S, layer 
 ) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gap/4.12.2/libexec/pkg/genss/gap/genss.gi:883 called from
...  at *stdin*:14
you can 'return;'
```

Comment: Have you checked the [FAQ](https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#6.2)?

Comment: @DanielB no sir which point .